# Terraformで、GCPのArmorを作成する方法について

Tags: google-cloud, terraform

Google Cloud Platform上に、Cloud Armorを作成するために、
https://runble1.com/gcp-terraform-cloud-armor/を参考に、
次のようなTerraformファイル(*.tf)を作成し、実行したところ、

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.3.6" # Terraformのバージョン（指定したバージョン以外エラーとなる）
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 3.5.0" # Providerのバージョン
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file("../xxxx-xxxx.json")
  project     = "xxxxx-999999"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

# Armor
resource "google_compute_security_policy" "test_policy" {
  name = "xxxx-devxxxx-armor-01"

  rule {
    action = "deny(403)"
    match {
      expr {
        expression = "request.path.matches('/auth/realms/master/*')"
      }
    }
    preview  = false
    priority = 0
  }
}
```

以下のような、matchブロック内にexprは記述できない旨のエラーが発生しました。
エラーを解消するには、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。
（どこを調べれば手がかりが得られるでしょうか？）

```
(venv) sasaki@kXXXXXXXXX:~/workspace/terraform-dp/terraform_test$ terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on main.tf line 25, in resource "google_compute_security_policy" "test_policy":
│   25:       expr {
│
│ Blocks of type "expr" are not expected here.
```

OSは、WSL2のUbuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Terraformのバージョンは、v1.3.6
GCPプロバイダのバージョンは、registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.5.0
です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答が得られない可能性があるため、以下サイトへもマルチポストしました。
<https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-create-gcp-armor-with-terraform-blocks-of-type-expr-are-not-expected-here/47802>

Comment: GCPプロバイダのバージョンを上げたらエラーが解消されました。<https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-create-gcp-armor-with-terraform-blocks-of-type-expr-are-not-expected-here/47802>